# Using next() from link outside div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have HTML structured as:

```
<h2>Title 1 <span class="open">&nbsp;</span></h2>

<div class="licensesection" id="licensepage1">
//stuff
</div>


<h2>Title 2 <span class="open">&nbsp;</span></h2>

<div class="licensesection" id="licensepage2">
//stuff
</div>
```

And jQuery (loaded after HTML):

```
$('.open').click(function () {
$(this).next('.licensesection').slideToggle('slow');
$(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

But the addition of `next()` is preventing it from working. I also tried

`.next('div.licensesection')`

but that doesn't work either. Am I misusing the `next()` selector?

Comment: next() is for siblings.

Comment: Use `$(this).parent().next(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned, [**`next()`**](http://api.jquery.com/next/) is for siblings:

> `next()` - Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the
>   set of matched elements.

The `<span>` is a child element of the `<h2>` which itself is the previous sibling of the `<div>`, so use `parent()` to get to that `<h2>`, and then `next()` to get to the `<div>`, like so:

```
$('.open').click(function () {
  $(this).parent().next('.licensesection').slideToggle('slow');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/HZ5k7/1/)